# Automatically reload current file in vim after code formatter has run on save

Tags: vim, autoformatting

I am trying to to acheive the following every time a file is saved in Vim under Windows 10 (Vim 8.2):

1. Auto format the file (using an external tool, e.g. Uncrustify)
2. Reload the formatted file in Vim (I want to see the newly formatted file)

Right now I am able using `autocmd` to autoformat the file, by adding the following to my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufWritePost * silent! !start /min Autoformat.bat <afile>
```

The problem is that the file contents is not updated on the screen (I still see the unformatted file). I have to go out of focus and come back to see a prompt to reload the file. *What is missing to refresh the file?*

After some research, I have tried the following so far:

1. Add `autocmd BufWritePost * !edit` (manually, it works)
2. Add `autocmd BufWritePost * !redraw`

but it does not seem to work.

---

Note: The `silent! !start /min` silence the annoying command prompt that used to flash by on every save (on Windows).

---

The following worked for me on Windows:

```
set autoread
autocmd BufWritePost * silent! !C:\Users\epoirier\Documents\BufWritePost.bat <afile>
autocmd BufWritePost * redraw!
```

I still see the console flashing by for (less than) a second, but I can live with that since Vim reloads the file automaticaly and I can keep working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can't test this on Windows 10 right now, but on Linux I'm trying a similar setup that works:

```
autocmd BufWritePost * silent! !start /min Autoformat.bat <afile>
autocmd BufWritePost * edit
autocmd BufWritePost * redraw!
```

file reload is triggered with `edit` (as you already discovered) **without** prepending `!`

`!` executes a shell command but `edit` is a vim command, we don't need `!` before the command (same thing applies to `redraw`).

`redraw!` is necessary because `silent` [can mess up the screen](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/silent-makes-my-vim-go-blank) when used for an external command.

---

an alternative (and I think better suited) solution to reload the file is by using `autoread` option instead of triggering `edit`. from `:help autoread`:

> `'autoread'` `'ar'`
>
> When a file has been detected to have been changed outside of Vim and it has not been changed inside of Vim, automatically read it again.

lines on `.vimrc` become:

```
set autoread
autocmd BufWritePost * silent! !start /min Autoformat.bat <afile>
autocmd BufWritePost * redraw!
```

Comment: I have just tried both options and none works on my Windows machine. The first option (with `edit`, no `autoread`) does not automatically update the screen after the save. I have to go out of focus and come back to see the reload dialog box. The second option (no `edit`, with `autoread`) does not automatically update the screen however if I loose focus and come back to Vim, the screen is updated without the reload dialog box.

Comment: @BobMorane oh that is really unfortunate :( can you provide more infos about your setup? e.g. are you running vim from the terminal or are you using gvim? -- as soon as I get to my windows 10 machine at work I'll try to replicate your setup and hopefully come up with a working windows solution.

Comment: I use GVim 8.2 on Windows 10. I use no plugins and the formatter used is Uncrustify (which is called inside the script). I have a small `.vimrc` file which I can share with you if needed. Basically I only set a couple options for line numbering and so on. Thanks for taking the time, I appreciate.

Comment: I have tried your second solution on my Linux machine and it works as expected.

Comment: I updated the question with the working lines from my `.vimrc` on Windows. Your solution works.

Comment: @BobMorane I'm very happy to hear this! glad I helped you!